# Simple clojure/refer to clojure throwing compilation error

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, la-clojure

I'm new to Clojure development and I was following Eric Rochester tutorials on the subject, most precisily: [Tokenization Part 4](http://writingcoding.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/tokenization-part-4-organization.html)

When namespaces are introduced Eric asks the users to write this header on a file named `word.clj` as I did:

```
(in-ns 'word)
(clojure/refer 'clojure)
```

And using La Clojure plugin for intellij IDEA I launch a Clojure REPL and get this:

```
Clojure 1.5.1
user=> (load-file "C:/folder/Dev/src/clojure/src/word.clj")
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: clojure, compiling:(C:\folder\Dev\src\clojure\src\word.clj:2:1)
```

For such a simple two line program I wouldn't expect these to be missing dependencies, especially when I'm referring the closure core library.

Can someone explain what kind of noob mistake I'm doing?

Thank you.

Comment: I would also give cursive clojure plugin a shot over la clojure, as la clojure is not being actively developed anymore.

Comment: Hey @RedDeckWins, I'm going to wait until cursive comes into a proper release build, my IntelliJ didn't like the plugin although I followed to set up to the line, including testing older versions. I'm sticking to la clojure for the next few months and then swap :)

Comment: I also have light table on the side...

Comment: which version of Intellij are you using, just curious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespace `clojure` is obsolete (that blog is quite old, 2008). Use `clojure.core`:

```
user> (in-ns 'word)
;; => #<Namespace word>
user> (clojure.core/refer 'clojure.core)
;; => nil
```